# catch up in meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have seen the phrase in this passage :

> Protesters and law enforcement continue to clash in Hong Kong, and US
>   companies are finding themselves ***caught up in*** the political
>   strife.

Source : https://www.cnet.com/news/blizzard-hearthstone-and-the-hong-kong-protests-heres-what-you-need-to-know/

What does it mean in this context?

Comment: See the second definition [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/caught-up-in-something)

Answer (score 1):

**"Catch up"** and **"caught up"** actually have two different meanings, idiomatically speaking.

To be **"caught up"** in something means that, without actually intending to participate in something, you become involved with it anyway, and experience consequences as a result.  The US companies were in Hong Kong to do business; they weren't there to protest, nor were they there to enforce laws.  However, because they're in Hong Kong, they're affected by both the protesters and the law enforcement officials: they're *"caught up"* in the event of the Hong Kong protests.

You could think of it like being accidentally caught in the net of a fisherman while swimming in the ocean; the fisherman wanted to catch fish rather than humans, but pulled in his net without seeing you there, and unintentionally got you as well.  You were literally *caught up* in the fisherman's net.

**"Catch up,"** on the other hand, means to literally or figuratively increase your speed so that you're going as fast as someone or something.  In the literal sense, if you're driving and want to pass a car, you have to *catch up* to it before you can drive past it.  In the figurative sense, the phrase is generally used to mean increasing your knowledge about a subject so that your knowledge of the subject is as great as someone else's.  For example, someone might say, *"Catch me up on what you've been doing since I saw you last,"* or, *"I haven't studied all week; I need to catch up on my reading before the test."*